# What is zoom level 15 equivalent to?

Tags: android, google-maps

For some reason this seems much harder to find than I thought it would be. I am working with a map display and I have set the zoom level to 15:

```
mapController.setZoom(15);
```

What are the different zoom levels equal to in distance? I am assuming is some kind of log or exponential scale. If I choose 1 or 18 for the zoom levels, what is the approximate distance that will be displayed on the screen for each zoom level on a map?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [MapController.setZoom](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapController.html#setZoom%28int%29):

> Sets the zoomlevel of the map. The value will be clamped to be between
>   1 and 21 inclusive, though not all areas have tiles at higher zoom
>   levels. This just sets the level of the zoom directly; for a
>   step-by-step zoom with fancy interstitial animations, use zoomIn() or
>   zoomOut().
>
> Parameters: zoomLevel - At zoomLevel 1, the equator of the earth is
>   256 pixels long. Each successive zoom level is magnified by a factor
>   of 2.
>
> Returns: the new zoom level, between 1 and 21 inclusive.

Comment: Ok, so at zoom level 1 the screen displays about 40000km, then at level 2 20000km, level 3 10000km and so forth?

Comment: so soemthing like 40000/(2^n) should give me my answer where n is the zoom level...seem right?

Comment: I'm sure that will be a _very_ rough estimate but that also doesn't factor in the screen width. See this post for a bit more details. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6452332/1101070

Comment: Also, with the projection that Google Maps uses, the map scale varies by latitude -- it's different at the equator than in London, say.

Answer (score 2):

See the entry in the [OpenStreetMap FAQ](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/FAQ#What_is_the_map_scale_for_a_particular_zoom_level_of_the_map.3F) (OSM uses the same tiling system as Google).

Comment: According to that, then, a zoom of 15 is equivalent to a scale of 1:14,0000.

Comment: how do I convert that to a distance in km? I just need to get a rough estimate

Comment: What does 14,0000 means?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to zoom to include certain places take a look at [zoomToSpan](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapController.html#zoomToSpan%28int,%20int%29).  That might help some of your issues.  I used it to zoom in on a group of points, and just calculated the min/max points and was good to go.