# Google maps distance based on the zoom level

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3

I have used google maps for displaying some locations using markers, based on the user's current location. User's current location is the center point of the map. The default `zoom level` is `12`. In default, I displayed markers within 300 miles(approximately in my case) distance only.

In that how can I do the following,

1) If `decrease` the zoom level, I need to increase the distance that should display markers within the increased distance also. how much distance should I increase in miles (i.e. `Zoom level` is `11`) ?

2) If `increase` the zoom level, I need to decrease the distance that should display markers without the increased distance. how much distance should I decrease in miles (i.e. `Zoom level` is `13`) ?

Please suggest me there is any built-in option to do that ...

Comment: Related question: [What is zoom level 15 equivalent to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717279/what-is-zoom-level-15-equivalent-to) (concerned with Android, but the Google Maps Javascript API v3 is the same).

Comment: Related question: [Google Maps V3 - How to calculate the zoom level for a given bounds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048975/google-maps-v3-how-to-calculate-the-zoom-level-for-a-given-bounds)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but when you increase the zoom by 1 you must divide the distance by 2. When you decrease the zoom by 1 you must multiply the distance by 2.

The formula would be:

```
newDistance=(Math.pow(2,initialZoom-currentZoom)*initialDistanceAtInitialZoom)
```

Demo: (drawing a circle where the formula above will be used to calculate the radius)

```js
function initialize() {
   var map    = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                  zoom: 4,
                  minZoom:2,
                  center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.52, 13.4),    
                  noClear:true,
                  zoomControl:true,
                  draggable:false,
                  scrollwheel:false,
                  disableDefaultUI:true
                }),
      circle  = new google.maps.Circle({
                  map:map,
                  center:map.getCenter(),
                  radius:300000*1.609344
                }),
      ctrl    = document.getElementById('radius');
    
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(ctrl);
    
    google.maps.event.addListener(map,'zoom_changed',
    
    (function(z,r){
        return function(){
          var radius=(Math.pow(2,z-map.getZoom())*r);
          circle.setRadius(radius);
          ctrl.innerHTML=(radius/1609.344).toFixed(3)+' miles(zoom:'+map.getZoom()+')';
        }
      }(map.getZoom(),circle.getRadius())
    ));
    google.maps.event.trigger(map,'zoom_changed');
  
}

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,body,#map_canvas{
          height:100%;
          margin:0;
          padding:0;
       }
       #radius{
          background:#fff;
          padding:4px;
          font-size:14px;
          font-family:Monospace;
       }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"><div id="radius"></div></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

I found the zoom_changed event after a quick google

ex:

```
 map.addListener('zoom_changed', function() {
    infowindow.setContent('Zoom: ' + map.getZoom());
  });
```

more info Google Api Docs [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-properties)

Comment: oh no! I need the distance calculation based on the zoom level. Please read my question