# How to set zoom level in google map according to miles?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to set zoom level according to miles. What should be zoom level of google maps in 1 to 20 miles?

Comment: I think this is good explaination:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002563/android-how-do-i-set-the-zoom-level-of-map-view-to-1-km-radius-around-my-curren

Comment: @Trivial :- i have already go through this link but it's not help me..