# How to calculate zoom value at specific coordinate for meters per points on Google Maps SDK for Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Google Maps SDK for iOS has pretty good method for calculation zoom value based on coordinate, distance in meters and length in pixels: zoomAtCoordinate:forMeters:perPoints:. But I can't find something similar at Google Maps SDK for Android. Also I can't find some workaround for that. Who faced such a task? Any solutions or ideas.

Comment: So basically you want to have the ratio between meters and pixels for a given zoom level, right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a dedicated function for setting the zoom level the way you mentioned, though I think your question is pretty much the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002563/android-how-do-i-set-the-zoom-level-of-map-view-to-1-km-radius-around-my-curren).

In short, you can do something like this:

```
Circle circle = mGoogleMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
    .center(new LatLng(0, 0))
    .radius(getRadiusInMeters());           
getZoomLevel(circle);
```

or you can try to calculate the right zoom level recursively as another answer in that thread mentioned which I do not recommend.