# How can I zoom an Android map to a specific width in meters?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm working on an Android app that uses Google Maps to overlay images on the map. I want to zoom the map to a specific width in meters (e.g. when editing an overlay to move it), but I can only set the zoom level directly. How can I calculate the appropriate zoom level based on the desired width in meters?

I've already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002563/android-how-do-i-set-the-zoom-level-of-map-view-to-1-km-radius-around-my-curren), but it doesn't seem to work for me. The zoom is about right, but not completely. I need it to be exactly right.