# How to set the default zoom level on new Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, embed

I readed many question, map help, product forums and so on... but I never find the answer just this "It is not possible". I can't believe it.

So how can I set the default zoom level on an embed Google Map?

Now I have this link for my map: https://mapsengine.google.com/map/edit?mid=zV4QqQ0y5KZs.kFj05lIIpS5s

I was tried thi `z=10` parameter in the URL, it doesn't work. Is there any other parameter, or maybe something `JavaScript` tricks to set up the zoomlevel? Or something other HTML parameter like `data-zoom` or something...?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way to apply a higher zoom-level(lower zoom should be possible with a trick)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set zoom level in google map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454229/how-to-set-zoom-level-in-google-map)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems the `&z=nn` parameter now works.

Try this:

`https://mapsengine.google.com/map/viewer?mid=zV4QqQ0y5KZs.kFj05lIIpS5s&z=10`

Answer (score 6):

I use this code to initialize my map:

```
var map;
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, -3),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
```

That's centered in Spain.

Comment: hence the question: how do I connect this code with my embed code? Can you update your answer with embed code, please?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Try this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70809/how-to-change-default-zoom-in-the-google-embedded-map

Answer (score 2):

The new embedded google maps do not have the Z index more, you have to **first** set the zoom level you want on the google maps site, and **afther that** click on the setting button and get the iframe code for the zoomed map.
You can not change the zoom level in the setting window, that is why you have to zoom the map first directly in the google maps.

Than paste this code in your html page and it should work, at least this worked for me.

Comment: hmm, tx, but didn't work for me: i created a new map, zoomed to the correct level, then added markers, labels, etc, then shared & embedded, and the zoom level still appears to be an arbitrary default..

Comment: Worked for me though (on the regular Google Maps page). Thanks.