# Google Maps API - Show all local roads when zoomed out

Tags: google-maps, zooming, google-roads-api

Hi my first post on Stackoverflow.

When viewing country areas in Google maps the screen is very sparse. I would like to make all local roads visible at a wider loom level. At present the local roads disappear at zoom 11z. I would like to be able to see local roads at 10z. In city areas 11z is ok but in country areas the map in nearly empty at 11z.
Compare these two maps at the same zoom.
https://www.google.com.au/maps/@-29.2066221,150.1589212,11z
https://www.google.com.au/maps/@-27.5583332,153.0584176,11z

The country area actually has a lot of roads but are 'local' and therefore are not visible. How do I increase the amount of detail shown? I have not been able to find a style setting that shows local roads at a wide zoom level.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will depend on the area that you are showing. For example, in New York you can view all the roads by using the `zoom=12` while in the Philippines you need `zoom=13` to view the roads clearly. So I suggest you to don't focus on the zoom level, and use Style map to view the roads clearly.

Just check this example on how to use [style maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling) on the roads.

Here is the part that shows the color of the roads.

```
{
featureType: 'road',
elementType: 'geometry',
stylers: [{color: '#38414e'}]
},
{
featureType: 'road',
elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
stylers: [{color: '#212a37'}]
},
{
featureType: 'road.highway',
elementType: 'geometry',
stylers: [{color: '#746855'}]
},
{
featureType: 'road.highway',
elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
stylers: [{color: '#1f2835'}]
},
```

For more information about the zoom level, check this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454229/how-to-set-zoom-level-in-google-map) specially the answer of Rahul Shinde

Comment: I have tried some of the style setting to enhance the minor roads but I can not find a setting that will make a hidden road become visible.

Comment: Is there a setting for density of text and roads? Where can I find a list of all map settings.

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by making it appear to Google that you have a giant monitor and are viewing at a high zoom.

Zoom out the map using the + - icons in the corner.

When the roads disappear zoom out the webpage, (cmd-minus on Mac)(ctrl-minus on PC),

Zoom back in the map using the + - icons in the corner makes the roads re-appear.

This can be repeated for several zoom levels.