# Get zoom for city

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Script for Chicago:

```
var current = new google.maps.LatLng(41.8333925, -88.0123393);
map.setCenter(current);
```

Script for Danville:

```
var current = new google.maps.LatLng(36.5925975, -79.5510265);
map.setCenter(current);
```

It work ok, but I must use for this setZoom.

So if I use:

```
map.setZoom(10);
```

This is good for Chicago, but for Danville it is too far (12 is good).

Is there a similar function to setZoom, which will bring me a map only to the boundaries of a given city? Chicago and Danville are only examples.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11454897/3575770

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this code :

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
      }
    });
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265055/how-to-get-google-maps-api-to-set-the-correct-zoom-level-for-a-country#answer-7294526)

Comment: Unfortunately still zoom is the same.