# Android MapView zoom to a radius

Tags: android, zooming, android-mapview

in my application i have a MapView.

i want to change the zoom of the map according to the radius the user set.
i've found the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6452332/1092770) link, but the problem is that the function consider only the screen's width.. i want to height to be consider too.

for instance: if i want to see radius of 1km - the function in the link will show me a width of 1km but not a height of 1km..
it is really important for me that it will show it on both width and height even if when height is 1km the width is 1.5km

how can i do it ?

Comment: Could you get a way to do this?

Comment: not really... the link in the question is the best answer i found so far..

Answer (score 4):

Here is the working code and with accurate result.

1) Make a circle on object with desired radius

```
Circle circle = mGoogleMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions().center(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).radius(getRadiusInMeters()).strokeColor(Color.RED));           
        circle.setVisible(true);
        getZoomLevel(circle);
```

2) Pass that object to this function and set the zoom level
Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939983/how-does-this-google-maps-zoom-level-calculation-work)

```
public int getZoomLevel(Circle circle) {
if (circle != null){
    double radius = circle.getRadius();
    double scale = radius / 500;
    zoomLevel =(int) (16 - Math.log(scale) / Math.log(2));
}
return zoomLevel;
}
```

Comment: what is 500 in this case ? what is 16 in this case ?